# Spring Boot API returns json without labels

Tags: java, json, spring, hibernate

I'm building a rest API with Java Spring Boot and I'm running into a problem, I have the following class with a method (which is in my controller for testing purposes, I will send its logic to the service later):

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/readings")
public class Readings {
    @Autowired
    private ReadingService readingService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public List<Reading> getRelevant(@RequestParam("start") String start, @RequestParam("end") String end){
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:MM:SS");
        start += " 00:00:00";
        end += " 23:59:59";
        try {
            Date startdate = df.parse(start);
            Date enddate = df.parse(end);
            return readingService.getRelevant(startdate, enddate);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

This makes use of a service that calls the following repository function:

```
@Query("SELECT pmtwofive, pmten, recording FROM Reading WHERE recording >= ?1 AND recording <= ?2")
List<Reading> getRelevant(Date start, Date end);
```

Everything works fine, except for the format of the result:

```
[[10,20,1505801743816],[14,21,1505802311976],[14,21,1505802330610],[10,13,1505803302960],[10,13,1505803321966]]
```

Instead of this, I was expecting something like I get when using the CrudRepository from hibernate querying my whole table instead of just these three values:

```
{
    {
        pmtwofive: 10,
        pmten: 20,
        reading: 1505801743816
    },
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

What should I do to get my expected result? Thank you!

```
Reading Class:

package com.amione.models;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.sql.Timestamp;

@Entity
public class Reading {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
    private long reading_id;

    private int sensor_id;
    private int function;
    private int directionstart;
    private int pmtwofive;
    private int pmten;
    private int checksumlow;
    private int checksumhigh;
    private Timestamp recording;

    public long getReading_id() {
        return reading_id;
    }

    public void setReading_id(int reading_id) {
        this.reading_id = reading_id;
    }

    public int getSensor_id() {
        return sensor_id;
    }

    public void setSensor_id(int sensor_id) {
        this.sensor_id = sensor_id;
    }

    public int getFunction() {
        return function;
    }

    public void setFunction(int function) {
        this.function = function;
    }

    public int getDirectionstart() {
        return directionstart;
    }

    public void setDirectionstart(int directionstart) {
        this.directionstart = directionstart;
    }

    public int getPmtwofive() {
        return pmtwofive;
    }

    public void setPmtwofive(int pmtwofive) {
        this.pmtwofive = pmtwofive;
    }

    public int getPmten() {
        return pmten;
    }

    public void setPmten(int pmten) {
        this.pmten = pmten;
    }

    public int getChecksumlow() {
        return checksumlow;
    }

    public void setChecksumlow(int checksumlow) {
        this.checksumlow = checksumlow;
    }

    public int getChecksumhigh() {
        return checksumhigh;
    }

    public void setChecksumhigh(int checksumhigh) {
        this.checksumhigh = checksumhigh;
    }

    public Timestamp getRecording() {
        return recording;
    }

    public void setRecording(Timestamp recording) {
        this.recording = recording;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your reading class look like?

Comment: @caiocpricci2 I updated the question with the added class!

Comment: where did you get `[[10,20,1505801743816],[14,21,1505802311976],[14,21,1505802330610],[10,13,1505803302960],[10,13,1505803321966]]
`??? Is it from your client side? or you just print it from your server side?

Comment: client side, running: `http://localhost:8000/api/readings?start=2017-09-19&end=2017-09-19`

Comment: Check if the same result will be if you eg `findAll()` or `findOne()` insteed of your projected query Or even `return new Reading()` with some data filled in. Its just to exclude that repository is doing something fancy here.

Comment: nothing, it's all done by the @Query annotation with my repository function that's in my question, I only want those 3 to be exposed, is there a better way? I'm new to this. yeah the default findAll() functions report the data correctly as a json, but I want a functiont that gives me all the attributes and one that gives me just those 3

Comment: In general it should work out of the bax (returning object causes json serialization) but I usually annotate my properties with `JsonProperty`, otherwise it gets ignored. Annotate your properties in model class , create new reading object, fill it with something and return. See what happens then. IMHO Spring repository is returning tuple insteed of entity (but still hadles is in some way), resulting if serialization of array of arrays. Why is it happening idk, but it looks just like that

Comment: I already did the annotations, returning just one object does output in the correct format, but it shows everything `{"reading_id":0,"sensor_id":0,"function":0,"directionstart":0,"checksumlow":0,"checksumhigh":0,"Pmtwofive":25,"Pmten":10,"Recording":10}` I only want to do a select for 3 values in that class and return a list of those objects, what would be the best way to go around doing that? so far the @Query annotation just feels like black box magic programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I have the answer. It must be done with custom constructor:

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@Entity
public class City extends AbstractEntity {

@Column
private String name;

@Embedded
private Geopoint centre=new Geopoint();

public City(){}
public City(String name){
    this.setName(name);
    }
//  @OneToMany(mappedBy="city")
//  private Set<Place> places;

}
```

Repository:

```
public interface CityRepository extends JpaRepository<City, Long>{

    City findOneByName(String name);
    @Query("SELECT name FROM City")
    public List<City> findMethod1();

    @Query("SELECT c.name FROM City c")
    public List<City> findMethod2();
```

Controller:

```
@Autowired
private CityRepository cityRepository;
@GetMapping("/test")
public List<City> test(){
    List<City> ret=new ArrayList();
    ret.addAll(cityRepository.findMethod1());
    ret.addAll(cityRepository.findMethod2());
    ret.addAll(cityRepository.findMethod3());
    return ret;
}
```

and the result:

[image]

As you can see, 3rd method works. I told you it will came up.

As empty values are still serialized, you can use a DTO object to encapsule only required fields (and `SELECT new EntityDTO(field1,field2,field3) FROM Entity`)

Another option would bo to configure Jackson to not to serialize null values with annotation or configuratio, but that is just beyond the scope of question.

Comment: Thanks I will try it out once I get the chance and come bsck to update this!